# AJAX/APACHE/PHP/HTACCESS configuration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

I have two apache server version 2.2.3 one in CentOS & 2.2.21 another one in winxp .

I need to save huge data more than 600 form fields via ajax post response.

Ajax working fine while I am execute the ajax & form script file in winxp apache (XAMPP) server its fine. Data has been saved but take some time to execute and I will get the response from server as data saved successfully.

While I am running the same the ajax & form script file save huge data more than 600 form fields via ajax post response in CentOS Apache server I am not getting any response from server while I print the posted data at server and alert the success response text I will get only partial amount of data inputs which I was posted.

Is there any Apache conf settings?

Please help me?

code look like below :

```
    var ajax_obj = create_ajax_object();  //*** object will be created using this function   ****//
    ajax_obj.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajax_obj.readyState == 4)
        {   
            alert(ajax_obj.responseText); 

        }
    }
    ajax_obj.open('POST','execute_ajax.php', true);
    ajax_obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax_obj.setRequestHeader("Content-length", param.length);
    ajax_obj.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    ajax_obj.send(param);   //**** param is huge data string more than 600 form fields.  **** //
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have the suhosin patch installed in your CentOS environment? If so, check its configuration for the limits on allowed POST parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase your max_input_vars in php.ini max_input_vars available since PHP 5.3.9.

You can set this in to your php.ini file or .htaccess

.htaccess

```
php_value max_input_vars 10000000000   (nearly 1 GB )
```

php.ini

```
max_input_vars = 10000000000
```